# Latex, using Babel

Tags: babel

I recently started to work under Xubuntu 16.04, and I'm facing problems with
the Polish Babel package, though it worked before.

I prepared a very simple latex example to show the problem:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
This is an example.
\end{document}
```

And here is system's replay:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./mintest.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/02/01>
Babel <3.9q> and hyphenation patterns for 3 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/utf8.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.dfu)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.dfu)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omsenc.dfu)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty

! Package babel Error: Unknown option `polish'. Either you misspelled it
(babel)                or the language definition file polish.ldf was not found
.

See the babel package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.310 \ProcessOptions*

?
```

Could you, please, help me to solve the problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You need to use `apt-get` in order to install the language support packages. At the least, `texlive-lang-polish`

Answer (score 1):

The error message suggests that your TeX installation is incomplete; do

```
apt-get install texlive-lang-polish
```

Doing a full install of TeX Live is usually better, barring disk space constraints.